# Left_join fill NA entries with data values from the second dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I have two fairly complicated data.frames and managed to simplify the first step of my problem here. I have a reference table and another that contains my data as follows:

**REFERENCE**

```
ref <- structure(list(group = c("A", "B", "C"), position = c("a", "a", 
"b")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(position = c("a", "a"), value = c(1, 1, 2), name = c("foo", 
"bar")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I used `left_join(ref,df,by="position") %>% arrange(name)` to obtain:

> ```
> 1 A     a            1 foo  
> 2 A     a            1 bar  
> 3 B     a            1 foo  
> 4 B     a            1 bar  
> 5 C     b           NA NA
> ```

The ideal output however is:

> ```
>   group position value name 
>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>
> 1 A     a            1 bar  
> 2 B     a            1 bar  
> 3 C     b            0 bar
> 4 A     a            1 foo  
> 5 B     a            1 foo  
> 6 C     b            0 foo
> ```

I would like the name column to replace NA with the input from df and the value column's NA with 0. In the real df, I have more than foo in the name column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `crossing` to get the combinations, then `replace` the 'value' column values to 0 where the 'position' columns are not equal

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
crossing(ref, df %>% 
                rename(position2 = position)) %>%
    arrange(name) %>%
    mutate(value = replace(value, position != position2 , 0)) %>% 
    select(-position2)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  group position value name 
#  <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>
#1 A     a            1 bar  
#2 B     a            1 bar  
#3 C     b            0 bar  
#4 A     a            1 foo  
#5 B     a            1 foo  
#6 C     b            0 foo
```

Comment: This fails when I add a second unique name. Would it be ok if I edit the question?

Comment: @user171558. yes,  please. do. so that it. becomes easier to understand  (also show expected output for that)

Comment: @user171558 I made the changes.  If there are duplicates in both datasets for the `by` column, the `left_join` creates replicates the number of rows, but it may not be the same as in `crossing` (based on the output you showed)

Comment: Thanks!!! I guess I will rename the original df and use this same approach.